# Get all system time zones in C++

Tags: c++, api, timezone

How to get all system time zones using c++ code? I need all time zones, to display them in a dropdown box.

I have tried using ReadOnlyCollection timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
But it seems this api is supported only in C#

Is similar feature available for C++ ?

Comment: I assume your question is for Windows. One way is to find them in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`.

Comment: to access HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE might need special permission.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Windows?  Are you using Win32? WinRT? UWP? C++/CLI (.NET)? Something else?